# Суждение, утверждение, существование

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, семантика

Читал учебник и наткнулся на определение суждения.

Суждение – мысль, содержащая утверждение о наличии в действительности некоторого положения дел.

Слегка запутался. Утвердительное предложение сообщает о существовании некоторого положения дел, но у меня получается тавтология, когда я читаю определение. Утверждение подразумевает существование, как и наличие. Мысль, в которой говорится, что некая ситуация имеет место быть и тут плюс еще слово наличие. Или тут имеется в виду подтверждение? Мысль, содержащая подтверждение о наличии в действительности некоторого положения дел. Объясните пожалуйста. Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, если он вам таковым показался.

Comment: Жаль, что Вы не сказали, в каком учебнике наткнулись на это определение. Судя по формулировке, это учебник не по логике и не по риторике. По философии? Ну, такие учебники нужно читать последовательно, а не "натыкаться" на отдельные формулировки. Разберитесь сначала, что означает философская концепция "положение дел". В любом случае, я думаю, что Вы задали свой вопрос не в том сообществе.

Comment: Учебник "Основы логики" Бочарова и Маркина.

Answer (score 1):

Тут не идёт речь о "подтверждении". Подтверждение — это тезис или факт, добавляющий весу уже имеющемуся представлению о чём-либо. "У нас есть догадка о существовании лохнесского чудовища и ряд подтверждений: свидетельства очевидцев, видео- и фотоматериалы".

У вас в определении использовано слово "утверждение". В данном контексте оно использовано в одном из самых популярных своих значений: "положительная формулировка". В этом плане слово "утверждение" антономично слову "отрицание". При чём "положительность" формулировки вовсе не обязывает её нести положительное значение. "Я утверждаю, что лохнесского чудовища нет". В данном случае мы имеем просто тезис почти синонимичный отрицающей фразе "я отрицаю существование лохнесского чудовища". Смысловая разница здесь заключается в том, что слово "утверждаю" даёт фразе направленность во вне, некий заявительный характер. То есть это не просто моё частное мнение, но ещё и некоторая мысль, которую я буду отстаивать при необходимости. В этом плане формулировка более решительная и жёсткая, чем "я думаю" или "мне кажется", каждая из которых не подразумевает того, что человек будет отстаивать своё мнение при необходимости.

Но вернёмся к вашей фразе и попытаемся разобрать её, перефразировать.

"Суждение — мысль, содержащая утверждение о наличии в действительности некоторого положения дел".

Мысль — слово в значение близком к словам "тезис", "представление", "соображение", "идея"

Содержащая — слово в значение близком к "включающая", "имеющая в себе среди прочего", "постулирующая" (в данном контексте)

Утверждение — слово в значение близком к "положительная формулировка", "заявление", "уверенное мнение"

Наличие — слово в значение близком к "присутствие", "нахождение"

Действительность — слово в значение близком к "реальность", "материальность" (в противовес наличию в мыслях, в гипотезах, в фантазии)

Некоторого положения дел — тут, надеюсь, не надо ничего объяснять.

Таким образом, мы можем перефразировать фразу так:

"Суждение — это идея, постулирующая уверенное мнение о присутствии в материальном мире некоторого положения дел".

Так как в учебнике использованы наиболее точные и ёмкие слова, попытка заменить их на синонимы создаёт несколько кривую и местами спорную формулировку. Однако для вас это всё же удобная конструкция, позволяющая взглянуть под свежим углом на поставившую в замешательство фразу.

От себя добавлю, что само определение из учебника мне не нравится. Я бы выразился иначе, но это уже за рамками вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ, но разве "подтверждать" здесь не имеется в виду как: Засвидетельствовать достоверность, действительность, наличие и т. п. чего-л?

Comment: Нет. Это значение, о котором Вы сейчас говорите, это для ситуации, когда Коля сказал, что видел лохнесское чудовище, а Маша подтвердила, что это правда было так. То есть она выступила свидетелем, засвидетельствовала достоверность.